# How to enable the laptop function F1-F12 keys by default instead of assigned multimedia "hotkey" option

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, dell-latitude, function-keys

How do you make the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys default to the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> key as opposed to the "hotkey" function that is assigned to it.
An industry-specific software that I use daily utilized the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys in almost every function, and I can't seriously have to keep hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> every time.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/235351/how-to-choose-whether-your-function-keys-are-f1-f12-keys-or-special-keys/amp/ scroll down to find setting in control panel or windows mobility center

Comment: That's often a bios setting.